# Microsoft Graph API: (400) Bad Request

Tags: c#, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-teams

I am using Microsoft Graph API to create a Group using `POST https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups`, but I am getting a `400 - Bad Request` response.

My code:

```
string url = AuthenticationRequest.Microsoft_Graph_API_URL + "/groups";
Dictionary<string, string> headers = new Dictionary<string, string>();
headers.Add("Authorization", "Bearer xxxxxxxxxxxxx");
WebRequests webReq = new WebRequests();
var ddd = new
{
    description = "Group to help readers",
    displayName = "Reader Assist",
    groupTypes = new List<String>()
    {
    "Unified"
    },
    mailEnabled = true,
    mailNickname = "rhelp",
    securityEnabled = false
};
string body = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(ddd);
string response = webReq.PostRequestWithheaders(url, headers, body);
```

Code of Method `PostRequestWithheaders`

```
public string PostRequestWithheaders(string url, IDictionary<string, string> headers, string bodyData)
{
    try
    {
        System.Net.WebRequest webRequest = System.Net.WebRequest.Create(url);
        webRequest.Method = "POST";
        webRequest.ContentType = "application/json";
        if (headers.Count > 0)
        {
            foreach (var item in headers)
            {
                webRequest.Headers.Add(item.Key, item.Value);
            }
        }
        Stream dataStream = webRequest.GetRequestStream();
        byte[] postArray = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(bodyData);
        dataStream.Write(postArray, 0, postArray.Length);
        dataStream.Close();
        WebResponse response = webRequest.GetResponse();
        dataStream = response.GetResponseStream();
        StreamReader responseReader = new StreamReader(dataStream);
        string returnValue = "";
        returnValue = responseReader.ReadToEnd().ToString();
        responseReader.Close();
        dataStream.Close();
        response.Close();
        return returnValue;

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw;
    }
    return "";
}
```

The Token is generated using the scope `openid offline_access Calendars.ReadWrite.Shared profile email https://graph.microsoft.com/User.Read`

Can anyone help here what is wrong with this code?

Comment: You've tagged this as `microsoft-graph-sdks` but your code isn't using the SDK? Is there a reason why?

Comment: I see you retagged this post, but my question still remains; is there a reason you're not using the SDK for this?

Comment: I got an answer from this post
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59451788/re-generate-access-token-from-refresh-token/59452947#59452947

Answer (score 1):

Your property names are improperly cased. They should all begin lowercase:

```
var ddd = new
{
    description = "Group to help readers",
    displayName = "Reader Assist",
    groupTypes = new List<String>()
    {
    "Unified"
    },
    mailEnabled = true,
    sailNickname = "rhelp",
    securityEnabled = false
};
```

Comment: Yes, I had used lower case too but error was the same. anyhow I updated in my question too.